Gigabyte Wifi not working with Ubuntu 24
I bought a new motherboard, tons of RAM, decent CPU (Core I7).
Wifi doesn't work and is apparently not supported natively.
Does anybody know if there are drivers known to work?
The board:
Gigabyte Z790 Eagle 1.0
Wifi : Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX211
The OS
Ubuntu 24.04.01 with latest updates. I just reused the disk on my old machine.
Thanks for any hint.
Elodie

Please edit the question and add the missing info. What is the exact make and model of the wireless chip set not the motherboard. Also edit and correct the version info. Ubuntu does not have a version just called 24.

This question is similar to: No hope for AX211 wifi working on ubuntu 20.04?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I checked following the accepted answer and discovered that a driver .deb package for the AX211 adapter is available for Ubuntu 24.04.
